# I would prefer icon to be up a little further and balanced

Tags: html, css, position, icons, font-awesome

I have an issue about the position of an icon beside `navbar` menu. I would prefer the icon to be up a little bit further and balanced. I'm getting the icon from font awesome.

```css
 li a i {
   font-size:1em;
   color: darkseagreen;
   margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ATHLETES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-square-full"></i>PRODUCTS</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: remove `s` from `<i class="fas fa-square-full" ></i>` if you are using `font-awesome`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "up a little bit further".  If the icon is to be "up a little bit further", then it won't be balanced: I am assuming by balanced you mean vertically centered with the item "Products".

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: flex` to achieve this

```css
li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a i {
        font-size:0.6em;
        color: darkseagreen;
        margin:0 5px 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ATHLETES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-square-full" ></i>PRODUCTS</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nwu5d5d2/1/)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Font awesome **Version 5.0.5** to support this.
Just change to

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-square-full" ></i>PRODUCTS</a></li>
```

For older Font awesome **Version 2 onwards**, you could use

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-square" ></i>PRODUCTS</a></li>
```

https://fontawesome.com/icons/square?style=solid

```
fa-square
```

Here is the working example in jsfiddle for your case using Font awesome 4.4.4

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/3672/

You need to update HTML and CSS as follows

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ATHLETES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-square" ></i>PRODUCTS</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And you should class name instead of directly referencing the elements in css

```
.custom-font {
        font-size:0.6em;
        color: darkseagreen;
        padding-right : 5px;
 }
```

Updated with your classes only

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/3671/

use

```
li a i {
        font-size:0.6em;
        color: darkseagreen;
        margin:0;
    }
```

Comment: what is `custom-font` here and why do we need at this point? can't we solve without adding this?

Comment: Yes you can I have updated with your code itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/3670/

Comment: the questioner is using `fa-square-full` rather than `fa-square`